# jquery : how to toggle div after using search function on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a search function to highlight text (function 2) in different chapters. In parallel most of this text is stored in div called content to ease reading. You can toggle these div to read the text (function 1).

When text is found by function 2, it's no longer possible to toggle the text in this chapter. I suppose this is related to use of "this" in function 1 (If I delete this it works) or handlers (if I add live in front of click in function 1 it works but live is deprecated and remplacement "on" is not working).

```js
// function 1 : toggle content when clicking the button
$(".chapter button").on('click',function(f) { //live deprecated to be replaced
  f.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id)
  $('#' + id + '+*').toggle();
  // toggle is not working when highlight function located in item in this specific chapter
});

// function 2 : highlight content
$('#monForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitted')

  // clear form
  var str = $('#valeurForm').val();
  $('#valeurForm').val("");
  console.log(str);

  // highlight
  var strCut = str.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < strCut.length; i++) {
    // grey chapter where the word is located
    $("div[class='chapter']:contains(" + strCut[i] + ")").css("color", "#929aab");
    // and highlight in red specific word
    // but i want to highlight all occurences of the word in this chapter ? how can I define index d ?
    $("div[class='chapter']:contains(" + strCut[i] + ")").each(function(d) {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(strCut[i], '<font color="red">$&</font>'));
    });
  };

});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .content {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="search" id="monForm">
    <input type="text" id="valeurForm">
  </form>
  <div class="chapter">
    chapter 1
    <button type="button" id="chapter1">Display content</button>
    <div class="content">
      content chapter1
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="chapter">
    chapter 2
    <button type="button" id="chapter2">Display content</button>
    <div class="content">
      content chapter2
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery est inclus ! -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was your `$(this).html()`. The `.replace` that you did removes the event listener of your button, because it  modifies the DOM. Instead of getting the whole `.html()`, I did it with `.children()`, and then replaced just the text of it.

About replacing all the occurrences of the `chapter` word, you could use a Regular Expression. Using a string will replace just the first occurrence of the string. With the regular expression you can replace all of them.

```js
// function 1 : toggle content when clicking the button
$(".chapter button").click(function(f) { //live deprecated to be replaced
  f.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id + '+*').closest('.content').toggle();
  // toggle is not working when highlight function located in item in this specific chapter
});

// function 2 : highlight content
$('#monForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitted')

  // clear form
  var str = $('#valeurForm').val();
  $('#valeurForm').val("");
  
  // highlight
  var strCut = str.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < strCut.length; i++) {
    // grey chapter where the word is located
    $("div[class='chapter']:contains(" + strCut[i] + ")").css("color", "#929aab");
    // and highlight in red specific word
    $("div[class='chapter']:contains(" + strCut[i] + ")").each(function(d) {
      var regex = new RegExp(strCut[i],"g")
      $(this).children().each(function (index,element) {
      const text = $(element).html().replace(regex,'<font color="red">$&</font>')
      $(element).html(text)
      })
    });
  };

});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .content {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="search" id="monForm">
    <input type="text" id="valeurForm">
  </form>
  <div class="chapter">
    chapter 1
    <button type="button" id="chapter1">Display content</button>
    <div class="content">
      content chapter1 and the second ocurrence of chapter also highlighted
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="chapter">
    chapter 2
    <button type="button" id="chapter2">Display content</button>
    <div class="content">
      content chapter2
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery est inclus ! -->
</body>
```

**EDIT**

I wasn't clear enough about the errors, sorry, and I've noticed the right solution.
The point is that, instead of modifying the parent element, I've changed the text of the childrens. When you change the whole `html`, you remove the listener of your buttons when you add it again to the html, and that's why isn't possible to toggle the divs.

Comment: thanks @mthrsj ! There are still 2 things i don't get :
why and where is the replace() in my proposal changing div id ? I dont get it in the code ?

I also would like to highlight the word in chapter title. I made a try adding the title in a div under the div chapter. Its highligted but I get back to being unable to toggle. So maybe it's important I understand your answer for my question above :-)

Comment: @nicoParis you want a better explanation about the code? It yes, I'll do an edit

Comment: I would like to understand where my code is modifying div id and your is not please.

Comment: @nicoParis, answer fixed

Comment: Thanks I understand now :-)
Do you know if I can enable the listener for the button after having changed the div ?

Comment: @nicoParis, you could add it again, but it doesn't seem to be the best way to do it, attaching the event handler after every search..